# How can I do this when I clicked button with data it will selected value on select option data with NextJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Hello I am beginner with NextJS how can I do when I click button it will selected values on select option data like example with this link https://www.mobicom.mn/mn/shop/newnumber#/ after click first 4 digit below select options it will change on select option above how can I do this and fetch data next to first 4 digits?
[This is buttons with data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oy2EV.png)

[This is select option tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yr46i.png)

When i click 7801 button it will get 78 01 on select option?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i didnt do anything right now because dont have any idea i just did fetch my data and made interface

Comment: Go to the react docs and read about state https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/managing-state

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you trying to work out how to get data and handle states

```
const App = () =>{
  const [state,setState] = useState();

  return (
    <select onChange={(e) => setState(e.currentTarget.value)} value={state}>
      <option value="1">Value 1 </option>
      <option value="2">Value 2</option>
      <option value="2">Value 3</option>
    </select>
  )
}
```

This is a very basic example, we use the "onChange" on the select to get its currectly selected value, once you "change" it it will set the state to the value
e.g. setState('some value here') changes the value of state

Comment: Thank you so much, i have buttons with data fetched from api and when i click one button it will get data to selected value how can i do this? ill add picture below